# Should we still use classes or functions that require std::iterator if std::iterator is deprecated?

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, c++17

I heard `std::iterator` is deprecated in C++17.

For example, like functions from `<algorithm>`, more likely we're going to be using `begin()` and `end()` member functions of objects which return iterator, like `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc.

Or like range-based for loops, where we will need `begin()` and `end()` which return iterator as well.

So therefore, if `std::iterator` as the base class is deprecated, should we even use member functions like `begin()` and `end()` or use other functions in the STL that require an iterator?

Comment: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/05/08/std-iterator-deprecated/

Comment: I guess the real question would be: Have you ever **used** `std::iterator`? If you grep all the C++ code you ever wrote, how many instances of `std::iterator` (the literal, exact text) can you find? I bet that you never used it, and it's deprecated precisely because it's mostly unnecessary, and partly confusing.

Answer (score 13):

> For example, like functions from `<algorithm>`

None of the functions from `<algorithm>` require `std::iterator`. It's fine to use them despite the deprecation of `std::iterator`.

> more likely we're going to be using begin() and end() member functions

None of those require the use of `std::iterator`.

> which return iterator as well.

Iterators are not deprecated. The class template `std::iterator` is deprecated.

> should we even use member functions like begin() and end() or use other functions in the STL that require an iterator?

Yes. Although, I would recommend using them through `std::ranges` when convenient (in C++20).

> So iterators inside of object/class like `std::vector<int>::iterator` are not inherited from `std::iterator`?

Standard library iterator types are defined by the standard library implementation. Technically, they could inherit from `std::iterator` but they are not required nor guaranteed to be inherited from it. Whether they inherit from `std::iterator` or not, they are not themselves deprecated.

---

`std::iterator` used to be intended to be used as a base class for custom iterators. Unless you are defining a custom iterator, you would not have been using it in the first place. If you are defining a custom iterator, you should not use `std::iterator` anymore. Note that it was never necessary to use `std::iterator` for this purpose.

Comment: So iterators inside of object/class like `std::vector<int>::iterator` are not inherited from `std::iterator`?

Comment: They are not required to inherit from `std::iterator`. Until it is completely removed from the C++ standard they may inherit from it, or they may not. Whether they do or not is immaterial.

Answer (score 7):

The deprecation of `std::iterator` is purely deprecating it use as a base class.

Using `begin()` and `end()` and iterators in general isn't affected by this at all.

Basically, all this is saying is that when you define an iterator, you should have something like:

```cpp
template <class T /* ... */>
class my_iterator {
    // the following names are what `std::iterator` defines for you:
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = T&;
    using pointer = T*;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    // ...
};
```

...and *not*:

```cpp
template <class T /* .. */>
class my_iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T> {
// ...
};
```

It also means the iterators in the standard library are intended to be done pretty much the same way (which they mostly have been, but depending on how you read it, there's an argument that older versions of the standard at least implied that they should be implemented by inheriting from `std::iterator` as well).

Since you mention `begin()` and `end()`, I suppose it's worth adding an unrelated point: it is generally better to use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` rather than the member functions of various collection classes. By doing this, your code can then work with built-in arrays, rather than just classes that define `begin()` and `end()` as member functions. But this is entirely unrelated to `std::iterator` being deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`std::iterator` is an iterator **building block**. It's not a valid iterator, and definitely not *the* iterator. The concept of iterators is by no means abandoned. There are no "classes or functions" in the C++ library that require `std::iterator`. None. There are classes and functions that use iterators in general, as a concept, but that has nothing whatsoever to do with `std::iterator`.

You have probably never used `std::iterator` anyway, since its only use from a user perspective is to implement custom iterators... So you'd have only used it knowingly if you implemented custom iterators *and* chose to derive them from `std::iterator`. The standard library was free to use `std::iterator` as it saw fit, but this was in implementation detail and there was no expectation in the C++ standard that any of the various iterators offered by the C++ library would actually use `std::iterator`.